# php/sql - phpmyadmin valor binário mostrar em web page

Tags: php, html, sql

[image: imagephp][image: imagemhtml]

Tenho uma base de dados de livros cada livro tem o seu ISBN, titulo etc e inclusive tem uma imagem, da qual fiz upload na base de dados para cada livro. só que o problema é que a imagem não aparece, faz o echo da imagem mas na realidade nao aparece(vejam as fotos).
O código que estou usando para chamar a imagem da base de dados é o seguinte:

```
 <?php
include('config.php');

$sql= "SELECT * FROM books WHERE category='computing'";
$r=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0">
<tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th> Title </th>
    <th> Author's name</th>
    <th> edition</th>
    <th> year</th>
    <th> category</th>
    <th> publisher</th>
    <th> quantity-in-stock</th>
    <th> price</th>
</tr>

<?php while($books =mysqli_fetch_object($r)){?>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $books->ISBN;   ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->Title;  ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->Authorsname; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->edition;?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->year;   ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->category;   ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->publisher;  ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->quantityinstock; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $books->price; ?></td>
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'"/>';
    <td> <a href="shoppingcart.php?ISBN=<?php echo $books->ISBN; ?>">Order Now</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

A base que estou usando é phpmyadmin e la fala "binário" por favor veja a foto. Desculpem se é pergunta básica, mas sou nova nisto e não tou entendo muito bem.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você cometeu um pequeno equivoco ao usar a função `base64_decode` em vez `da base64_encode`. A função base64_encode converte os dados da sua imagem em binario para que possa ser interpretada com o MYME base64 pelo navegador.

Corrigindo fica:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'"/>';
```

Quando você usava o base64_decode o navegador não conseguia interpretar o conteudo, pois não era um base64 valido.

Comment: oi, tentei mas ão funcionou, vou colocar o codigo todo. assim pode ser algo que não esteja a fazer bem

Comment: Observe que a linha que possui o comando echo não está dentro das tags do php (se realmente no seu codigo estiver assim, deve estar sendo impresso  a linha inteira na sua tabela). Eu testei com imagem png (image/png) e teve o comportamento experado. Não sei o motivo, mas já tive problemas em exibir imagens com a extensão .JPG (em maiusculo em vez de em minusculo.). De qualquer forma tente com um mime diferete.

Comment: voce testou com as tags do php?

Comment: Sim, coloquei dentro das tags do php.

Comment: Ja tentei e deu certo,obrigado